# Is there a variable to toggle Emacs 24.4 elisp return "noise"?

Tags: echo-area, eval-expression

In Emacs 24.4, every time I evaluate a form in `ielm` or using `C-x C-e` it prints a lot of extraneous output that while useful, sometimes gets in the way. As an example,

```
(+ 1 1)
;=> 2 (#o2, #x2, ?\C-b)
```

Is there a variable I can use to disable printing this extra information and have it just display `2` like it used to?

Comment: When you say "evaluate", do you mean C-x C-e?

Comment: I mean C-x C-e and *ielm*. I'm not aware of a single way of evaluating elisp that doesn't return this extra information by default.

Comment: @wdkrnls, `C-j` in `*scratch*` shows no extra info, also `e` in https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy.

Comment: The extra information only appears in the echo area. If you evaluate with `C-u C-x C-e` to get the output in the current buffer, it does not appear. Isn't that what you do if you wish to insert the result somewhere?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen IIUC, he doesn't want to insert it anywhere, he just finds this extra information in the echo area unhelpful and wants to hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a permanent change, you can arrange things with a bit of advice:

```
(defvar mute-eval-expression-print-format nil
  "Set to t to mute eval-expression-print-format")
(defun mute-eval-expression-print-format (orig-fun value)
  (if mute-eval-expression-print-format
      ""
    (funcall orig-fun value)))
(advice-add 'eval-expression-print-format
        :around #'mute-eval-expression-print-format)
```

Now set `mute-eval-expression-print-format` to `t` in order to mute the extra output.

Note that this uses the new advice mechanism (introduced with emacs 24, I think).

Comment: Well OP explicitly mentioned emacs 24.4 so it should be good ;-)

Comment: @syl20bnr Indeed, but the comment could be useful to others that aren't so up to date.

Answer (score 4):

You can override `eval-expression-print-format` to return `""` or `nil`:

```
(defun eval-expression-print-format (value)
  ; return an empty string
  "")
```

See the [answer by **@Harald Hanche-Olsen**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3772/2355) for a way to override it temporarily.

Comment: It's a fine solution, but I'd hardly use the word “temporarily” to describe it. A bit of advice is in order (pun intended); see my answer.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Fair enough. :-) I'll remove "temporarily" from my answer.